# Combining dates in times series

Tags: r

I am working on a time series data in R. How can I convert the time of three column in one column or is there a way to work with all the three time column data given below to forecast transportation(no of times)

```
Year    Quarter Week        Product                transportation(no of times
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01    2 Door Bottom Mount      2115
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01    Built-in Ovens           7240
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01    Cooktops                 1032
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01    Dishwasher               39401
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01     Dryer                   49707
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01    Free Standing Ranges    41063
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01     French Door            12586
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01     Front Load              10180
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01      MHC                   17920
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01     Side by Side           102
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01     Top Load              66517
2010    2010-Q1 2010-01     Top Mount             11232
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02     2 Door Bottom Mount     2115
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02      Built-in Ovens        7325
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02      Cooktops              1116
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02       Dishwasher           41592
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02       Dryer               70886
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02 Free Standing Ranges    44957
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02  French Door            16632
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02  Front Load             14186
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02   MHC                   20224
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02  Side by Side            130
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02   Top Load              79830
2010    2010-Q1 2010-02  Top Mount               13312
```

Comment: How do you plan on comparing/using each of the three columns?

Comment: Hi Tim, I plan to forecast it by quarterly and yearly

Comment: You may convert variable `Week` to date-class  `df$date <-
 strptime(df$Week,"%Y-%U")` to have continuous variable in dataset. It's most precise information, because the other are derivations which you can extract by `year <- year(date)` and week  using `df$week <- format(df$date,'%U')`. Forecast is a topic which you have to deal with, to maximise performance. Simple linear model `model <- lm(transportation~product+date+week, date=df)`